# PostgreSQL reports a key violation, but that is not possible

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I have wrote a stored-procedure in PostgreSQL as an API to create contract and user in a same time (by postgrest).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION
auth.create_contracts(
  username text,
  password text,
  services json,
  province text,
  region text,
  type user_group,
  telephone text,
  mobile text,
  email text,
  start_date text,
  end_date text,
  organization_name text,
  contract_number text,
  name text,
  economy_code INTEGER,
  t_name text,
  t_phone text,
  t_ip text,
  t_email text,
  t_telephone text,
  t_prefer_contract text,
  area_state text,
  area_city text,
  area_county text
) RETURNS json
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
DECLARE
  _user_id INTEGER;
  _res json;
  _now DOUBLE PRECISION;
  _app_token text;
  _username text;
BEGIN
  SELECT random_string(64) INTO _app_token;
  INSERT INTO auth.users(
    username,
    password,
    role,
    services,
    app_token,
    province,
    region,
    type,
    phone,
    organization_name,
    mobile,
    email
  )
  VALUES (
    username,
    password,
    username,
    services,
    _app_token,
    province,
    region,
    type,
    telephone,
    organization_name,
    mobile,
    email
  );


  SELECT username INTO _username;
  SELECT id FROM auth.users WHERE users.username=_username
  INTO _user_id;

  INSERT INTO auth.contracts(
    user_id,
    start_date,
    end_date,
    organization_name,
    contract_number,
    economy_code,
    t_name,
    t_phone,
    t_ip,
    t_email,
    t_telephone,
    t_prefer_contract,
    name,
    area_state,
    area_city,
    area_county
  )
  VALUES(
    _user_id,
    start_date::TIMESTAMP,
    end_date::TIMESTAMP,
    organization_name,
    contract_number,
    economy_code,
    t_name,
    t_phone,
    t_ip,
    t_email,
    t_telephone,
    t_prefer_contract,
    name,
    area_state,
    area_city,
    area_county
  );

  SET TIME ZONE 'UTC-3:32';

  PERFORM (
    SELECT auth.contract_redis_function(end_date::TIMESTAMP, now()::TIMESTAMP,
                                        _app_token, username, 100000)
  );

  SELECT json_build_object(
      'status', 'ok',
      'app_token', _app_token
  )
  INTO _res;

  RETURN _res;
END;
$$;
```

users definition:

```
create table auth.users
(
    id serial not null
        constraint users_pkey
            primary key,
    username text,
    password text,
    role text,
    services json,
    app_token text,
    province text,
    region text,
    type user_group,
    contract_id integer,
    phone text,
    picture text,
    is_first_login boolean default true,
    is_locked boolean default false,
    is_active boolean default true,
    organization_name text,
    mobile text,
    email text,
    prefer_contact text
)
;

create unique index users_username_uindex
    on users (username);
```

contracts definition:

```
create table auth.contracts
(
    user_id integer
        constraint unique_contract
            unique
        constraint contract_user_01
            references auth.users,
    start_date timestamp,
    end_date timestamp,
    organization_name text,
    contract_number text,
    economy_code integer,
    t_name text,
    t_phone text,
    t_ip text,
    t_email text,
    t_telephone text,
    t_prefer_contract text,
    area_state text,
    area_city text,
    area_county text,
    name text,
    id serial not null,
    is_active boolean default true
);
```

I have a unique constraint on a key of users relation (id that is auto incremented)
sometimes when call the end-point raise an exception that key exists, but doesn't, and create record.
I don't know why!?
I have a similar problem when creating policy in a stored-procedure.

Comment: There is a race condition and use should use `INSERT ... RETURNING`, but that shouldn't lead to a constraint violation. Can you add the definitions of all involved tables and the exact error message?

Comment: Ok, I will add to post

Answer (score 0):

`username` is not unique in `auth.users`, so there is no guarantee that this query gets the correct `id`:

```
SELECT id FROM auth.users WHERE users.username=_username
   INTO _user_id;
```

You will get the `id` of *one of the* rows with that `username`.

If there are several such rows, you could get the wrong one, and the `UNIQUE` constraint on `contracts` will be violated when you insert the same number a second time.

The solution is to always get the correct `id` like this:

```
INSERT INTO auth.users (...) VALUES (...)
   RETURNING id INTO _user_id;
```

Then you will always get the `id` of the record you just inserted.